# A five level deep list

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I would like to create a five level deep list using the `enumitem` package. I found this suggestion on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935952/maximum-nesting-level-of-lists-in-latex) and implemented it as follows

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{9}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1st level
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 2nd level
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item 3rd level
            \begin{enumerate}
            \item 4th level
                \begin{enumerate}
                \item 5th level
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But still get the error `too deeply nested`. Using itemize environments is unfortunately not an option.

In the link provided it is mentioned that the `\setlistdepth{}` only works from a certain version on, how do I find out which version I am using?

Comment: To see which version of a package you are using it is best to look in the .log file and search for the particular package.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

LaTeX has a limit of depth of lists to save counters. However, you can clone the existing `enumerate` environment and increase the depth with [the enumitem pacakge](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem):

```
\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{6}
```

You then need to use `\setlist` to set up the counters for each depth, and use `\setlistdepth{}` to increase the default depth limit of 6.

[image]

### Note:

- Without the use of `\setlistdepth{9}` a depth larger than 6 will result in:

  > LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.
- Have tested this to a depth of 15 and seems to work fine, but if you have a high list depth, you really need to reconsider the formatting of the information that you are trying to convey.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{9}

\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{9}
\setlist[myEnumerate,1]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,2]{label=(\Roman*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,3]{label=(\Alph*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,4]{label=(\roman*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,5]{label=(\alph*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,6]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,7]{label=(\Roman*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,8]{label=(\Alph*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,9]{label=(\roman*)}

\begin{document}
\begin{myEnumerate}
\item 1st level
    \begin{myEnumerate}
    \item 2nd level
        \begin{myEnumerate}
        \item 3rd level
            \begin{myEnumerate}
            \item 4th level
                \begin{myEnumerate}
                \item 5th level
                    \begin{myEnumerate}
                    \item 6th level
                        \begin{myEnumerate}
                        \item 7th level
                            \begin{myEnumerate}
                            \item 8th level
                                \begin{myEnumerate}
                                \item 9th level
                                \end{myEnumerate}
                            \end{myEnumerate}
                        \end{myEnumerate}
                    \end{myEnumerate}
                \end{myEnumerate}
            \end{myEnumerate}
        \end{myEnumerate}
    \end{myEnumerate}
\end{myEnumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that is sweet! However, I still do not fully understand it. Changing the list definition and initialization to 
\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{9}
\setlist[myEnumerate,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]{label=(\arabic*)}
will take me to the 7th(!!) level before throwing the error. Why is that?

Comment: Have updated solution to a higher limit.

Comment: What do you mean it still doesn't? I have shown the above to work to a depth of 9 and tested it to a depth of 15? How much deeper do you want it to go?

Comment: no, no. It does work, I forgot to `\setlistdepth{}` b/c I didn't see it have any effect. And I just want to go to depth five, where it indeed is not needed

Comment: This is a wonderful solution.  However, references to labels do not include the complete nested location.  Is this implementable?

Comment: @beethree: Probably a good idea to post a follow up question.

Comment: @Peter Grill: [The follow up.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126879/a-follow-up-question-to-a-five-level-deep-list)

Comment: Any way for this to work [nicely?] with `pandoc` ?

Comment: @javadba: I don't know enough about `pandoc`. I suggest you  post a follow-up question and if relevant include a link to this question.

Answer (score 23):

I realize this answer doesn't satisfy the requirement of not using itemize, but I am adding it for completeness.

Since the 5-level depth constraint also applies to itemize environments, here is an example (using the same method proposed in Peter's answer) that increases the depth for the default itemize environment:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{20}
\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{20}

% initially, use dots for all levels
\setlist[itemize]{label=$\cdot$}

% customize the first 3 levels
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=--}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=*}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple, but unconventional way if you "just" need that little extra fifth level. Does not work when you need six or more levels and needs some manual hacking.

You can use

> \item []

to truncate the enumeration symbol and add it to you text manually.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item first level.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item second level.
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item third level.
            \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item fourth level.
                \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                %fake \begin{enumerate}
                    \item [] 1. fake fifth level.
                    \item [] 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    \item [] 3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                %fake \end{enumerate}
                \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            \end{enumerate}
            \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: Though it may work, I suggest sticking to the prepared and provided standard way, as outlined in other answers, here.

Answer (score 0):

The hack that I've been using to get that fifth level of nesting is to use itemize inside of enumerate.  It's the simplest, out-of-the-box way if you don't absolutely need numbering on the innermost layer.