# How can I create custom an environment with default left margin?

Tags: environments, indentation, paragraphs

--Edit-- (rewrite the code that I use currently to produce margin left)

This is code that I try to make a new environment (`leftwhitespace`) of, instead of writing these code that create list  with 1 item:

```
\begin{itemize} 
    \item[]
      line 1
      line 2
\end{itemize}
```

Want to create new environment `leftwhitespace` that will do as code above (add margin left):

```
\begin{leftwhitespace}
    line 1
    line 2
\end{leftwhitespace}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56813/197451

Comment: I want create custom environment vs each time add \hangindent=1em or leftmargin=3cm etc... vs suggested in tex.stackexchange.com/a/56813/197451. (Compare to html and css I want create class that can be included each time that I want instead write inline css.)

Comment: something like this-------- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51548/leftalign-labels-with-enumitem?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: the link above for more complete cases, I just need to add \hangindent=1em for the paragraph and this custom paragraph. (Soo I try create newenvironment, but the code that I put not works, I need to correct my code inside  newenvironment)

Comment: please place the complete code above for a valuable reply  starting with `\documentclass` and finishing with `\end{document}`

Comment: Please see the Edit that I made - I add exactly the code that I currently use to produce margin left effect for all environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well what you want, `changepage` already has an environment for that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[10]
\begin{adjustwidth}{3em}{0pt}
\lipsum[11-12]
\end{adjustwidth}

\lipsum[13]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ok, but how can be that code put inside newenvironment (I want to have default left margin)

Comment: You should explain what you want to do exactly.  This environment does not change the default lefty margin. It only changes the left margin inside itself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for solution, how can I create custom environment for solution that you suggested: you suggested:  \begin{adjustwidth}{3em}{0pt}
\lipsum[11-12]
\end{adjustwidth} -> (I want to write that) \begin{custom_adjustwidth}
\lipsum[11-12]
\end{custom_adjustwidth} (without each time write: {3em}{0pt}, I want to write {3em}{0pt} inside custom environment definition)

Comment: You can add something like this to your preamble: `\newenvironment{myenvt}{\adjustwidth{3em}{0pt}}{\endadjustwidth}`  and use it as `\begin{myenvt} ... \end{myenvt}`

Answer (score 2):

Does this solve your query:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{hanglist}[1][\parindent]{%
    \begin{list}{}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-#1}}
    }{%
        \end{list}
    }

\def\D{\par\noindent\makebox[1em][l]{-- }\hangindent1em}

\newcommand{\detail}[1]{\par\noindent\hangindent=\mylen\hangafter1-- #1}
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{-- }
\begin{document}
\begin{hanglist}[2cm]
\item\lipsum[1]
\item\lipsum[2]
\end{hanglist}

    Regular itemize
    \begin{hanglist}[1cm]
       \item First
       \item Second 
       \item Third
    \end{hanglist}

\subsubsection*{This is a header}
\D This is a detail
\D This is a detail that has too many words in it and consequently runs onto The next line of the page, and I want it to have a hanging indent.

\noindent\textbf{This is a header}
    \detail{This is a detail.}
    \detail{This is a detail that has too many words in it and consequently runs onto the next line of the page, and I want it to have a hanging indent.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks! can you please see edit that I made?