# How to make deeper list at lyx

Tags: lyx, lists, enumerate

Hello I saw this question here:
[A five level deep list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41408/a-five-level-deep-list)

My question is: How to do the same thing at LyX?
It's doesn't work for me when I put the the code at the preamble...

```
 % Preview source code

%% LyX 2.2.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1255]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}
\newlength{\lyxlabelwidth}      % auxiliary length 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\Roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=(\Alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label=(\roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,5]{label=(\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,6]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[enumerate,7]{label=(\Roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,8]{label=(\Alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,9]{label=(\roman*)}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\beginL 32132\endL}
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\beginL 4332234\endL}
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\beginL 432\endL}
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\beginL 423423\endL}
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\beginL 432432\endL}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to "update" the definition of `enumerate` it seems, see [Mark's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304515/586) to the question you refer to. If I add

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{9}
\renewlist{enumerate}{enumerate}{9}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\Roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=(\Alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label=(\roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,5]{label=(\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,6]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[enumerate,7]{label=(\Roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,8]{label=(\Alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,9]{label=(\roman*)}
```

to the preamble (note the `\renewlist` on the second line), it works fine here. The preview in LyX doesn't work, but the PDF is fine.

Note that instead of explicitly adding `\usepackage{enumitem}` you could add the *Customisable lists (enumitem)* module, as it looks like you have done in the code you show.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me :(  There are many errors - here is the first: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.36 \setlistdepth
                  {9}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: @Yoar Oops, I forgot to say I added the *Customized lists (enumitem)* module. Sorry, took that as a given. But alternatively, just add `\usepackage{enumitem}` before  `\setlistdepth`.

Comment: @Yoar Oh, just realized another possible cause of that problem: the `\setlistdepth` macro was added in version 3.0 of `enumitem`, so if you have an older version, then it wouldn't work.

Comment: Now it's works!!