# inline enumerate in Lyx

Tags: lyx, enumitem, inline

I am trying to get inline enumeration in Lyx. It's pretty handy for things like (i) this, (ii) inline, (iii) list.

In plain Latex I use

```
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
```

and later simply

```
\begin{enumerate*}
    \item bla
    \item bla
\end{enumerate*}
```

The same doesn't work in Lyx and when I try, I get "Too deeply nested" error and the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41408/a-five-level-deep-list) doesn't work in Lyx as there are many other Lyx-made environments in the document already.

How can I get inline lists in Lyx?

Comment: Maybe Lix uses `paralist`?

Comment: Can you post a MWE .lyx file where you get the "Too deeply nested" error?

Comment: What you describe works just fine in LyX (I tried), so you must be doing something more than that. I do get that error if I have an inline list in the fourth level of a nested enumerated list though, is that what you're trying as well? A minimal example as requested would be useful.

Comment: I had already a list >4 levels deep, but it was working fine I don't know how (I couldn't reproduce it later). Using the `enumitem` broke it somehow. Now I have used [Mark's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304515/44998) and everything works also with inline enumeration. Must make a rule of not trying hard on Friday evenings...