# Shorthand for deep enumitem

Tags: shorthands

I am trying to make an outline that may need to go 5 layers deep. In doing my research, I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41408/a-five-level-deep-list) which allowed for lists to go 9 layers deep apparently.

In testing it out I found that this works, however, I would like to use the shorthand that looks like this

```
\1 first label
    \2 second
        \3 third
            ...
```

How could I set it up so I can use that pretty short hand? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `easylist` package provides close to this functionality. Here's an example from the documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{easylist}
\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
§ First proposition.
§§ Interesting comment.
§§§ A note on the comment.
§§§ Another note.
§§§§ By the way...
§§§§§ This is a subsub...-proposition. 
§ Let’s start something new... 
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]