# Outlines package enumerate new list error

Tags: lists, enumitem

I'm making an outline and realized I needed another enumeration label. So, when I added the 5th one, and did the same \5 command, there was an error saying that it is an "undefined control sequence." What do I do? Please let me know and thank you.

```
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\Roman*.}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\Alph*.}
\setenumerate[3]{label=\roman*.}
\setenumerate[4]{label=\alph*.}
\setenumerate[5]{label=\arabic*.} %%% Not working%%%%%%
\newcommand{\tbf}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\tit}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\1 \tbf{Science}:
    \2 stuff 1
        \3 stuff 2
            \4 Stuff 3
                \5 HELP %%% Command not working %%%%%

\end{document}
```

Comment: By default only 4 levels of itemization/enumeration are supported by LaTeX and therefore most packages dealing with it. You'd have to manually add the next level to `outlines`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41409/117050 to add another level of enumeration (so that we can use a fifth level). It then changes the internals of `outlines` to support a fifth layer and to use `myEnumerate` as the list type.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[myEnumerate,1]{label=\Roman*.}
\setlist[myEnumerate,2]{label=\Alph*.}
\setlist[myEnumerate,3]{label=\roman*.}
\setlist[myEnumerate,4]{label=\alph*.}
\setlist[myEnumerate,5]{label=\arabic*.}
\newcommand{\tbf}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\tit}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xapptocmd\outline{\newcommand{\5}{\ol@tov\ol@v\item}}{}
  {\GenericError{}{Patching `outline` failed}{}{}}
\renewcommand\ol@commands[6]
  {%
    \renewcommand{\ol@toz}{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\ol@toi}{#2}%
    \renewcommand{\ol@toii}{#3}%
    \renewcommand{\ol@toiii}{#4}%
    \renewcommand{\ol@toiiii}{#5}%
    \renewcommand{\ol@tov}{#6}%
  }
\xapptocmd\ol@exit{{}}{}
  {\GenericError{}{Patching `\string\ol@exit` failed}{}{}}
\xapptocmd\ol@z{{\ol@inci\ol@incii\ol@inciii\ol@inciiii\ol@incv}}{}
  {\GenericError{}{Patching `\string\ol@z` failed}{}{}}
\xapptocmd\ol@i{{\ol@incii\ol@inciii\ol@inciiii\ol@incv}}{}
  {\GenericError{}{Patching `\string\ol@i` failed}{}{}}
\xapptocmd\ol@ii{{\ol@inciii\ol@inciiii\ol@incv}}{}
  {\GenericError{}{Patching `\string\ol@ii` failed}{}{}}
\xapptocmd\ol@iii{{\ol@inciiii\ol@incv}}{}
  {\GenericError{}{Patching `\string\ol@iii` failed}{}{}}
\xapptocmd\ol@iiii{{\ol@incv}}{}
  {\GenericError{}{Patching `\string\ol@iiii` failed}{}{}}
\newcommand\ol@v
  {%
    \ol@commands
      {\ol@decv\ol@deciiii\ol@deciii\ol@decii\ol@deci}
      {\ol@decv\ol@deciiii\ol@deciii\ol@decii}
      {\ol@decv\ol@deciiii\ol@deciii}
      {\ol@decv\ol@deciiii}
      {\ol@decv}
      {}%
  }
\newcommand\outlinev{\ol@type}
\newcommand\ol@incv{\begin{\outlinev}}
\newcommand\ol@decv{\end{\outlinev}}
\newcommand\ol@tov{}
\renewcommand\ol@type{myEnumerate}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{outline}
\1 \tbf{Science}:
    \2 stuff 1
        \3 stuff 2
            \4 Stuff 3
                \5 HELP %%% Command not working %%%%%
\end{outline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried adding it. But when I typeset, it gives me an error saying that "\5 change: implies new theory". What do I do?

Comment: The actual error was that its too deeply nested. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Dave2343 I'm not clairvoyant. I don't know what exactly you tried. It does work in the example above.