# Additional levels for itemize {Too deeply nested}

Tags: lists

For the shown MWE, I added levels till level 9 for itemize in the preamble, yet I do still get the error too deeply nested.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Simplified Arabic}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt} 
% incrase list level to 9 levels in itemize
\setlistdepth{9}

\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 

\begin{itemize} 
\item[]\begin{itemize}
\item
اللهجة الاخميمية الفرعية أو الاسيوطية:
\begin{itemize}
\item
علامتها المختصرة:
\begin{itemize}
\item
 في الكتب المصرية (أ2).
\item
 في الكتب الأجنبية 
\foreignlanguage{english}{(A2) – (L)}
.
\end{itemize}
\item
مشتقة من الاخميمية.
\item
كانت تستعمل من البهنسا الى أسيوط (ليكوبوليس).
\item
تُسَمَّى باللهجة ألاسيوطية أو لهجة ليكوبوليس.
\item
يرى البعض أنها تمتد الى منطقة ديوسبوليس الكبرى (طيبة أي الأقصر)، وبالتالي أطلق عليها إسم "اللهجة الليكوديوسبوليتية" (الأسيوطية الأقصرية): 
\foreignlanguage{english}{Lyco-Diospolitan}
\item
إستُخْدِمَت في الفترة ما بين القرن الثالث الميلادي والقرن الخامس الميلادي.
\item
تنقسم وثائق هذه اللهجة الى:
\begin{itemize}
\item
نصوص كتابية:
\begin{itemize}  
\item
إنجيل يوحنا (القرن الرابع والثالث).
\item
أجزاء من رسالة العبرانيين (أواخر القرن الخامس).
\item
أجزاء من رسالة فليمون (أواخر القرن الخامس).
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item
نصوص أبوكريفية: كتاب أعمال بولس (القرن الرابع والخامس).
\item
نصوص مانوية: تتبع بدعة ماني (ما بين القرن الرابع والخامس).
\item
نصوص غنوسية (القرن الرابع).
\item
خطاب عن شقاق ماليتيوس الأسيوطي (330 – 340م).
\item
نصوص غير أدبية.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you define the labels for the new levels. Or maybe, supplementary levels can apply only to own lists?

Comment: @Silva the answer has still not been accepted if it meets the requirement listed in the question - please do so by ticking the green check mark on the left

Answer (score 5):

Though I could not start the preview of the foreign languages however the main point was to address the nesting "too deep" error. This can be addressed as shown below. I am sure you will be able to add the missing languages at your end. All thanks go to Peter Grill @https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41409/197451   Have a shot and let the community know if there are further problems

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlistdepth{9}

\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{9}
\setlist[myEnumerate,1]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,2]{label=(\Roman*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,3]{label=(\Alph*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,4]{label=(\roman*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,5]{label=(\alph*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,6]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,7]{label=(\Roman*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,8]{label=(\Alph*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,9]{label=(\roman*)}

\begin{document}
\begin{myEnumerate}
\item 1st level
    \begin{myEnumerate}
    \item 2nd level
        \begin{myEnumerate}
        \item 3rd level
            \begin{myEnumerate}
            \item 4th level
                \begin{myEnumerate}
                \item 5th level
                    \begin{myEnumerate}
                    \item 6th level
                        \begin{myEnumerate}
                        \item 7th level
                            \begin{myEnumerate}
                            \item 8th level
                                \begin{myEnumerate}
                                \item 9th level
                                \end{myEnumerate}
                            \end{myEnumerate}
                        \end{myEnumerate}
                    \end{myEnumerate}
                \end{myEnumerate}
            \end{myEnumerate}
        \end{myEnumerate}
    \end{myEnumerate}
\end{myEnumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output is below

[image]

If you wish to alter the labels and add other you can do so --have a look below
You may like to accept the answer and give a raise for the efforts

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlistdepth{9}

\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{9}
\setlist[myEnumerate,1]{label=(--)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,2]{label=}
\setlist[myEnumerate,3]{label=(gf)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,4]{label=(\roman*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,5]{label=(\alph*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,6]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,7]{label=(\Roman*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,8]{label=(\Alph*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,9]{label=(\roman*)}

\begin{document}
\begin{myEnumerate}
\item 1st level
    \begin{myEnumerate}
    \item 2nd level
        \begin{myEnumerate}
        \item 3rd level
            \begin{myEnumerate}
            \item 4th level
                \begin{myEnumerate}
                \item 5th level
                    \begin{myEnumerate}
                    \item 6th level
                        \begin{myEnumerate}
                        \item 7th level
                            \begin{myEnumerate}
                            \item 8th level
                                \begin{myEnumerate}
                                \item 9th level
                                \end{myEnumerate}
                            \end{myEnumerate}
                        \end{myEnumerate}
                    \end{myEnumerate}
                \end{myEnumerate}
            \end{myEnumerate}
        \end{myEnumerate}
    \end{myEnumerate}
\end{myEnumerate}
\end{document}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, but can we do this with the "Itemize", not the "Enumerate" since I need a non-numbered list

Comment: Please see the alteration in the labels --accept the answer if okay

Comment: @ js bibra, the issue is, you migth need to use both, the itemize list for un-numbered items as well as the enumerate for numbered items: You might need both in the same file. I think this might be an issue.