# No tabular: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

Tags: itemize

I don't know why this won't compile. I checked opening/closing itemizes, counted items, tree depth, changed characters,...everything. I'm also using the same pattern throughout my whole file, but this is the only part where this error occurs:

```
\subsection{Heads-Up}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Mistakes
    \begin{itemize}
        \item unbalanced SB ranges
        \item insufficient SB limping (VPIP $\in [80\% , 90\% ]$ )
        \item underdefending BB
        \item 3-bet-pushing too tight
        \item adapting too slow (esp. pushes against limps from BB and estimating villain's limping range)
        \item calling Nash against recreationals
        \item wrong handselection for pushing vs. limping
        \item not differing between exploitative and GTO strategy
    \end{itemize}
    \item In Position (SB):
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Preflop
        \begin{itemize}
            \item $\geq 20$bb rather raise than limp
            \item $<20$bb rather limp than raise
            \item $<15$bb no raising range against regulars (GTO)
            \item if opponent plays tight-passive, just barrel
            \item avoid marginal preflop all-ins, put marginal hands in limping range
        \end{itemize}
        \item Postflop
        \begin{itemize}
            \item protection (rarely value/bluff bet)
            \item bet many flops with small sizings\\ $\rightarrow$ equity denial (fold out 6-outers)
            \item what part of range are we attacking?
            \item note a lot and mark hands to analyze bet sizings
            \item 2 streets of value
            \begin{itemize}
                \item vulnerable value hands: bet flop and turn
                \item (more or less) invulnerable value hands: check flop, bet turn, bet river
            \end{itemize}
            \item against recreationals and weak regulars always go for maximum
            \item check to protect equity
            \begin{itemize}
                \item every draw that can not bet/broke $\rightarrow$ check (e.g. open-ended straight draws without overcards)\\ $\rightarrow$ rather bet bottom pairs with overcard on straighty boards
            \end{itemize}
            \item delayed bets
            \begin{itemize}
                \item showdown value hands
                \item gutshot straight draws
            \end{itemize}
            \item do not waste equity by bet/folding high equity hands
        \end{itemize}
        \item Ranges
        \begin{itemize}
            \item adapt by not opening all of the min-raise/fold hands >20bb
            \item open-pushing 55-22 is also possible >20bb
            \item if we adapt >20bb range, also adapt ranges for shorter stack accordingly\\ (e.g. still min-raise more <20bb (like exploitative range))
            \item limp/folding range could be even wider in theory <15bb
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    \item Out of Position (BB):
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Preflop
        \begin{itemize}
            \item iso-raise polarized
            \item rather iso-raise suited connectors than offsuited Kx, Qx around 12bb
            \item analyze ranges with reads and population tendencies in HRC
            \item against opponents that limp much, we want to have low suited connectors and 1,2-gappers in our pushing-range since they actually perform better than some suited high card hands like (Q5s)
        \end{itemize}
        \item Postflop
        \begin{itemize}
            \item play straight forward against recreationals
            \item check/raise to stack off with any vulnerable top pair on 9xx boards and lower (mix in some gutshot straight draws or backdoor draws) with <15bb;\\ population calls down to much anyway
            \item do not check/raise/fold high equity hands\\ $\rightarrow$ do not waste equity
            \item the more broadway/highcard heavy the flop, the less we can raise for value\\ (we can not stack off with bad top pair for example) \\$\rightarrow$ range protection \\$\rightarrow$ except against recreationals and weak regulars (straight forward)
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: There is an extra `\end{itemize}` just below the last item `\item the more broadway/highcard`.

Comment: Oh thanks! Sadly this is still not the solution. :S

Comment: My workaround now is too replace the highest depth itemizes with \\ - since there are only one or two points anyway. But it's not really elegant and it can't be about the depth, since I use depth 5 throughout the whole thesis and this is just 4.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41408/a-five-level-deep-list help? A max default depth of 5 levels might be being exceeded somewhere.

Comment: @Chris, well, it is hard to know. The piece of code you showed compile normally here with standard class (after deleting the extra line as I said). Please, edit and post a minimal code so we can reproduce the error.