# Deep enumeration problem

Tags: enumerate

I am having trouble doing deep enumeration, that is: 1., then 1.1., then 1.1.1., ...

I manage to do this up until the fourth level: 1.1.1.1.

However, the fifth level fails, and I don't understand why.

My code is:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\theenumiii}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\theenumiv}
\renewcommand{\labelenumv}{\theenumv}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\theenumii\arabic{enumiii}.}
\renewcommand{\theenumiv}{\theenumiii\arabic{enumiv}.}
\renewcommand{\theenumv}{\theenumiv\arabic{enumv}.}
```

But the fifth level fails. The error is

> Command labelenumv undefined

Why is this happening on the fifth level but not on the fourth?

I tried `labelenumiiiii`, but it also did not work, and I am assuming the syntax `labelenumv` is the correct syntax.

Comment: By default, there are only 4 levels.

Comment: Is there a way or a package which allows more?

Comment: Yes, for example with `\newlist` command of `enumitem` package.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41408/a-five-level-deep-list?rq=1

Comment: @schtandard nearly, but the enumeration there does not include previous enumerations from upper levels. That is, in a deep level I want the enumeration to be 1.1.2.1.4. for example and not just 4.

Comment: @TheEmeritus Setting the label is a different issue from creating the list. For prepending the parent label, use `label*=` instead of `label=`.